Matlab and Python scatter3D haven't not the same result
I have the Matlab/Octave code to read and plot the *.mat data using scatter3 function.
This is the source code of Matlab/Octave:
clc;
clear all;
close all;
load ("myfile.mat")

figure()
delta=0;

for pt_1=1:size(RSSI,1)
for pt_2=1:size(RSSI,2)
  scatter3(X(pt_1,pt_2),Y(pt_1,pt_2),RSSI(pt_1,pt_2)-delta,400,RSSI(pt_1,pt_2)-delta,"s","filled");%,5,RSSI, "s", "filled");
  hold on;
end
end

for pt_1=1:size(RSSI_EC,1)
for pt_2=1:size(RSSI_EC,2)
  (X_EC(pt_1,pt_2),Y_EC(pt_1,pt_2),RSSI_EC(pt_1,pt_2)-delta,400,RSSI_EC(pt_1,pt_2)-delta,"s","filled");%,5,RSSI, "s", "filled");
  hold on;
end
end

for pt_1=1:size(RSSI_EC_DUO,1)
for pt_2=1:size(RSSI_EC_DUO,2)
  scatter3(X_EC_DUO(pt_1,pt_2),Y_EC_DUO(pt_1,pt_2),RSSI_EC_DUO(pt_1,pt_2),400,RSSI_EC_DUO(pt_1,pt_2),"s","filled");
  hold on;
end
end

scatter3(WAPPos(1),WAPPos(2),max(RSSI_mat),100,0,"c","filled");
axis off;
view(0,90)
cb=colorbar('south');
set(cb,'Title','[dBm]','fontsize', 24);
axis equal
colormap jet;
caxis([-100 0]);
xlim([0.5 35.5]);
ylim([0.5 7.5]);
zlim([min(RSSI_mat) max(RSSI_mat)]);

Now in Python, I use Matplotlib to do the same thing:
import numpy as np
import os
from numpy import size
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.io import loadmat
## load matfile
data_dict = loadmat("myfile.mat")
RSSI = np.squeeze(data_dict['RSSI']) 
RSSI_EC = np.squeeze(data_dict['RSSI_EC']) 
RSSI_EC_DUO = np.squeeze(data_dict['RSSI_EC_DUO']) 
X = np.squeeze(data_dict['X']) 
X_EC = np.squeeze(data_dict['X_EC']) 
X_EC_DUO = np.squeeze(data_dict['X_EC_DUO']) 
Y = np.squeeze(data_dict['Y']) 
Y_EC = np.squeeze(data_dict['Y_EC']) 
Y_EC_DUO = np.squeeze(data_dict['Y_EC_DUO'])
RSSI_mat = np.squeeze(data_dict['RSSI_mat'])
WAPPos = np.squeeze(data_dict['WAPPos'])

## PLOT SIGNALs
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
delta = 0

for pt_1 in range(RSSI.shape[0]):
    for pt_2 in range(RSSI.shape[1]):
        ax.scatter(X[pt_1, pt_2], Y[pt_1, pt_2], RSSI[pt_1, pt_2] - delta, s=100, marker="s")
for pt_1 in range(RSSI_EC.shape[0]):
    for pt_2 in range(RSSI_EC.shape[1]):
        ax.scatter(X_EC[pt_1, pt_2], Y_EC[pt_1, pt_2], RSSI_EC[pt_1, pt_2] - delta, s=100, marker="s", alpha=1)
for pt_1 in range(RSSI_EC_DUO.shape[0]):
    for pt_2 in range(RSSI_EC_DUO.shape[1]):
        ax.scatter(X_EC_DUO[pt_1, pt_2], Y_EC_DUO[pt_1, pt_2], RSSI_EC_DUO[pt_1, pt_2], s=100, marker="s", alpha=1)

ax.scatter(WAPPos[0], WAPPos[1], max(RSSI_mat), s=100, c='c', marker='o', depthshade=True)
ax.axis('off')
ax.view_init(90, -90)
plt.show()

There are some different things that I saw between Matlab and Python code:

The position of data (squares) in python were not like Matlab (what I expect)
In Python, the color of data are not correspond of the level of signal
In Python, the ar of the squares were not neatly like in Matlab.
I would like to add here the capture screen in order to describe more detail the problem that I have faced.


What are the things I need to modify in python to obtain the same result as Matlab?
Thank you

ax.set_proj_type('ortho') should solve one of your problems. Also, data is not colored according to viridis and the colobar is, and this baffles my understanding, maybe because it is lost in the all-alike names of your variables.

Yes, your command solve one of my problem (in term of the position). I appreciate your support very much. About the color of each point, I think there is a problem this the parameter c of function scatter (for ex: RSSI[pt_1, pt_2] - delta ...). But I don't know why? Additional, there is a problem: the plot that I have does not change the size (in horizontal) if i resize the figure. It does not like when I did in 2D plot.
